# How to get data DESC order and create pagination when working with elequent models laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pagination

I m writing this code for getting data in desc order but not working

```
$newspaper_more_info = newspaper_jobad::with('sector', 'newspaper', 'province', 'test', 'catagory')->where('test_id', $job_test->id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

and this code for creating pagination and getting data in desc order but it throws fatal error

```
$newspaper_more_info = newspaper_jobad::with('sector', 'newspaper', 'province', 'test', 'catagory')->where('test_id', $job_test->id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(15)->get();
```

Comment: Don't call `->get()` after `paginate(15)`

Comment: and what about order by

Answer (score 0):

it might get confuse to get id from which table, while doing order by. can you mention table name too in the order by clause

like `$newspaper_more_info = newspaper_jobad::with('sector', 'newspaper', 'province', 'test', 'catagory')->where('test_id', $job_test->id)->orderBy('newspaper_jobad.id', 'DESC')->get()`

as its eager loading the tables

if laravel 5.4 try

```
->orderByDesc('id')->get()
```

Comment: throwing error column not found 'newspaper_jobad.id' when use this 'newspaper_jobads.id' and nothing happens

Comment: are you getting result for `newspaper_jobad::with('sector', 'newspaper', 'province', 'test', 'catagory')->where('test_id', $job_test->id)` and what is the default order you are getting for the same?

Comment: which version you are using for laravel?

Comment: i am using laravel 5.4 version

Comment: have you check with this `orderByDesc('id')->get()`

Comment: yes I am getting the result for this query and works fine but i want to sort order of getting results on base of newspaper_jobad

Comment: they have changed `orderBy` to `orderByDesc` please check. If it helps please check sql log too, to get what query gets fired on applying of orderBy